# Why do ScrollViews not function in TableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have been building apps for half a decade and I have never been able to figure out how to get ScrollViews to work inside of TableViewCells when the cell height is automatically calculated (UITableView.automaticDimension) despite the scroll view inside the cell being properly configured.

Here is some code to get an idea of what I mean:

```
func configureViewComponents() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
    tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
    
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    
    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.register(EventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
    
    
    view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
}
```

Inside ScrollViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

ScrollView inside UITableViewCell ("line" is a view above the scroll view):

```
addSubview(mediaScroll)
mediaScroll.anchor(top: line.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: Concurrent.shared.deviceWidth, height: Concurrent.shared.deviceWidth)
```

ScrollViews will not function under these circumstances. However, if you replace "UITableView.automaticDimension" with an integer, suddenly they come back to life and function properly.

Does anyone in the community understand why?

Comment: I've actually noticed the same thing, I dug around and couldn't find an answer. I assume you are using "automaticDimension" for your cell height because you are interactively changing each cells height. Perhaps your best bet is to leave this luxury behind and calculate height manually for each cell when any expansion/shrinkage event occurs. I have submitted a bug report with Apple.

Comment: i think it because you need a height constraint for the scrollview, scrollview will not have a automatic height if you only set top,bottom,leading and trailing constraint

Comment: I updated the question to show the scroll view's constraints, please take a look @aiwiguna p.s. I am not talking about the ScrollVIew that TableViews come with.

Comment: if i am correct, you need bottom anchor on the code you share

Comment: @aiwiguna well done, you are exactly right! Do you have an explanation?

Comment: your cell did not calculate the height from scrollview because it did not have the bottom anchor, so it just uses cell default height. It constraint thing, I usually imagine how drawing square (scrollview) inside square (tableviewcell) without knowing either size and choose constraints I need so I can draw that two square